# CentOS 5.5 doesnt boot - possible failed RAID controller or hard drives?

Tags: linux, centos, raid

CentOS 5.5 does not boot past this point:

[image: centos 5.5 os doesnt boot past this point]

This machine has an Areca RAID controller with the OS on a RAID 1 mirror made from 2 SATA drives. There is a second array as well; a RAID 5 group with 4 SATA drives.

Based on the error message, what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: You should ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why is this not relevant for serverfault?  Is unix.stack... new?  Is there meta documentation somewhere that says which to post in when?

Answer (score 2):

You propably don`t have the right driver loaded in you initrd.

Apart from that - from your screenshot I only see 4 drives on 2 controllers. "SATA link down" does not look good. So you system can find 4 SATA drives but can`t access them.

What Linux distribution are you using, which version?

Answer (score 1):

What did you change before the reboot? Why the machine rebooted?

From what's on the screen there are 2 SATA controllers in the box, each with 2 drives plugged in. From your description, there should be 2 and 4 disks. Two disks have disappeared somewhere. Can you determine, why there are only 4 disks visible, instead of 6? Does re-plugging help? What does your raid controller say about the arrays?

Still, it's strange. If the boot disk disappeared, then where the kernel boot from? If the non-boot disks disappeared, why didn't the boot progress to the stage where a mount of some filesystem fails? If one disk from each group is gone, there shouldn't be any arror at the OS level at all... Something's very strange here.

Try re-booting again, but remove `quiet` option from `grub` command line, this should provide more information.